# Which LTE band should I use?

Tags: antenna, wireless, lte

**Background**

I am designing a basic IIoT device. When the sensor detects the parameter of interest, it transmits a message using an LTE modem. The modem is capable of Cat-M1 and NB-IoT, and I want to use NB-IoT because I read that it uses less power. Data rate has no importance. The bands I have available are 2, 4, and 12. This is based on my module's hardware, its IC (Industry Canada) modular certification, and my service provider. Here's a map of the coverage in my region with my provider, Rogers:
[image]

I am currently selecting the antenna for the device. In my research I found that antennas which support all those bands are too expensive. Therefore I will select an antenna to only support one or two of the bands. I can select the band 
in my modem through software using the command AT+CBAND.

I couldn't find too much information on characteristics of the bands on Google. I found that lower bandwidth is generally better for penetrating buildings, and higher bandwidth is better for fast data.

**Question**

For which LTE band(s), out of 2, 4, and 12, should I get an antenna? A constraint is the best reliability possible. Criteria are that I would like to have good penetration into buildings and use less power. I'm also interested in other parameters you think are relevant.

Comment: *because I read that it uses less power.* I don't think that's generally the case. It depends on your use case! Also, what you want is pretty irrelevant compared to what you can get: check whether theres NB-IoT or Cat-M1 deployments available to you, first.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fair enough, I haven't researched in NB-IoT as much as I want to yet. But the important part of the question, which band to use, stands I think regardless of whether I use M1 or NB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Therefore I will select an antenna to only support one or two of the bands. I can select the band in my modem through software using the command AT+CBAND.

Sadly, you're not in charge of selecting the band – your network operator is. So, all your considerations are in vain: you'll have to use what they are willing to offer you.

Comment: If I can't choose which band I get, do I have to support them all since I have no way of knowing which I'll be assigned? In this case, what is the point of AT+CBAND? I was assuming that all were available in the map I posted and I could choose which one to 'tune into'. I edited to provide more information on the bands I have available.

Comment: no, that's not how it works. The network defines what band a piece of equipment uses, not the equipment (that can, at best, make humble requests, but only if it's already on the network). We can't tell you. Your network operator can.

Comment: If it defines a band you don't have an antenna for will the modem simply not work? I thought that phones that supported some but not all of a network's total bands would still work.

Comment: as said, negotiation. I don't know on which bands your network operator offers the standards you want. You need to be compatible with that. Full stop.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I'll try to contact Rogers again (even though they're not very receptive to this type of question) and maybe I'll trial and error with a few antennas.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your question :)

> Criteria are that I would like to have good penetration into buildings and use less power. I'm also interested in other parameters you think are relevant.

In case of NB-IoT, as you've quoted, the channel bandwidth is 180 kHz, unlike the legacy LTE that could use channel bandwidths of 1.4 MHz, 3 MHz, 5 MHz, 10 MHz & 20 MHz. For this purpose of Coverage Enhancement (CE), the NB-IoT devices use repetitive transmissions wherein, a single Transport Block (TB) is transmitted across multiple consecutive subframes. In this manner, all these signals, that are delayed by a subframe duration, could add up in the multi-path propagation and receive enough energy to reach remote or hostile environments. You could still operate at the same transmission power level without ramping it up during the RACHing process.

In terms of antenna, NB-IoT devices use a single antenna. Amongst the 2nd, 4th and 12th bands of LTE, you could choose the lower frequency band, thereby enabling additional coverage.